# Django Formset - Access the primary key id input

Tags: django, forms, primary-key, modelform, formset

I want to render primary key id hidden input (`<input type="hidden" name="form-0-id" value="5" id="id_form-0-id">`) directly in my template. I know I can render whole form, but I don't want to have any labels there. Is there some way to get it using the formset? I used object `initial.id`, but it didn't work.

**Method:**

```
def getCellEditForm(self):      
    CellFormSet = modelformset_factory(Cell, extra=0, max_num=0)
    form = CellFormSet(queryset=Cell.objects.filter(pk=self.id))
    return form
```

**Template:**

```
{{ child.getCellEditForm.form.title }}
{{ child.getCellEditForm.form.parent }}   
{{ child.getCellEditForm.form.initial.id }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for subform in formset.forms %}
    {{ subform.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for subform in formset.forms %}
    <input type='hidden' id='id_form{{subform.id}}' name='form{{subform.id}}' value='{{subform.id}}' />
{% endfor %}
```